# Splitting video with ffmpeg gives weird output

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, split

I want to split a video into (mostly) equal parts of 120sec length. The code below works but only the first video output is of normal mp4 format. The others seem like they start at where the previous video ends but only like the video file was never cut

First video timeline image:

[image: video1 timeline]

next video timeline, as you can see it starts at 2min mark rather than at 0 as a separate video. Even though the file stats still show the video as being 2 minutes in length:

[image: video2 timeline]

```sh
ffmpeg -i 1146redmp4.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -map 0 -segment_time 120 -g 120 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*120)" -f segment 1146output%03d.mp4
```

If this is the correct output and not a bug. How do I have the video splits be output as their own video?

Comment: Simple way is: ```ffmpeg -i input.mp4 <encoding_options> -ss $((i*120)) -t 120 segment-$i.mp4```

Comment: [Try adding `-reset_timestamps 1` in the arguments.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your player doesn't like starting timestamps to be non-zero.

`ffmpeg -i 1146redmp4.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -map 0 -segment_time 120 -g 120 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*120)" -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment 1146output%03d.mp4`